# Does $\sum_n |\sin n|^{cn^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I recently asked a question about convergence of $\sum_n |\sin n|^{cn}$ for arbitrary $c > 0$ and it turns out that the terms of the series don't even converge, for any $c > 0$, so the series is always divergent. But what about  $\sum_n |\sin n|^{cn^2}$ for $c > 0$? Are there $c$ so that the series converges, and if there are $c > 0$ such that the series diverges, do the terms of the series still converge?

If that's too hard, what if we replace $n^2$ in the exponent by $n^\alpha$ for some different $\alpha > 1$? Which $\alpha$ do we know the answer for?

Comment: It seems unlikely that even the terms would converge to 0. I think it would imply too much regularity. I don't have a proof though.

Comment: That question is tightly linked with the irrationality measure for $\pi$, which is still largely an open problem; see the Wikipedia page for "Liouville numbers". If you replace, in your question, $n^2$ by $n^\theta$, than the series diverges for $\theta < 2$ and converges for $\theta > 7.6063...$ the irrationality measure of $\pi$. I'm not sure if it's known what happens at $2$.

Comment: @Sary I had no idea $2$ was such a special power of $n$ in the exponent. I modified my question to allow different powers of $n$ in the exponent. If you can elaborate your comment in an answer (with links about the "irrationality measure" etc. and how it pertains to this problem) I'll gladly accept.

Comment: I made a small mistake in my previous comment ; I'll expand as soon as I can.

Comment: Let $x_n = \sin n$, so we have $|x_n|\le1$ so using geometric series $\sum{(x^c_n)}^n$ is converge provided that $c<0$ and this for all $|x|<1$. It remains to check at $x_n=\pm 1$. which obviously fail. Finally we can say the series converge for all $|x_n|<1$ with $c>0$.

Comment: @Sary, At $\theta=2$ it is known to diverge. See my answer below. Also, for the convergence, larger $\theta$ is required. $7.6063$ will not be enough with current knowledge on the irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prove that $|\sin n|^{n^2}$ does not have a limit. We do this by showing that there are subsequences converging to different limits.

First, note that there is a subsequence converging to zero. This is because there are infinitely many $n$ with $|\sin n|\leq 1/2$.

For the other subsequence, consider for any integer $k$, 
$$
\begin{align}
|\sin n| &= |\sin(n -k\pi)|
\end{align}
$$
If we find a positive constant $C_1$ and infinitely many $n$, $k$ satisfying 
$$
\left| n - k\pi - \frac{\pi}2 \right|\leq \frac {C_1} n, \ \ \ (*)
$$
Then we obtain a positive constant $C_2$ and infinitely many $n$ with 
$$
|\sin n|\geq 1-\frac {C_2}{n^2}.
$$
Then by taking $n^2$-th power, we have
$$
|\sin n|^{n^2} \geq \left(1-\frac{C_2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2} \rightarrow e^{-C_2} \ \mathrm{as } \ n\rightarrow\infty.
$$

Now, we achieve ( *) by considering the continued fraction for $\pi/2$. Note that ( *) is equivalent to 
$$
\left|\frac n{2k+1} - \frac{\pi}2 \right| \leq \frac{C_3}{n^2}
$$
for some positive constant $C_3$.

To achieve ( *), let $n$-th convergent $p_n/q_n$ of the continued fraction of $\pi/2$ to satisfy $q_n$ is odd infinitely often. This is possible since $p_nq_{n-1}-p_{n-1}q_n=(-1)^n$. By this identity, no two consecutive denominators $q_n$'s are even.

Hence, your series $\sum |\sin n|^{cn^2}$ is divergent, since the terms diverge.