# Is there an elementary way to show $\sum_n (\sin n)^{2^n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I asked earlier whether $\sum_n (\sin n)^{n^k}$ converges for some $k$, and if so then what $k$, and I got an interesting comment/answer saying that supposedly it boils down to the irrationality measure of $\pi$, and the series should converge for example for $k \geq 8$. But that seems like pretty deep math. What if we make it easier to converge by considering $\sum_n (\sin n)^{2^n}$. Is there a fairly elementary way to see that this series converges?

Here's the original question. [Does $\sum_n |\sin n|^{cn^2}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141204/does-sum-n-sin-ncn2-converge?noredirect=1#comment2331794_1141204)

Comment: @SimonS sure, done.

Comment: A probabilistic approach is worth a try. If $X$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$, then $X+X^2+X^4+X^8+X^{16}+\ldots$ belongs to $L^1$, hence the series is almost surely convergent. In this framework, $\sin n$ behaves like $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison test. In fact, $2^n$ is greater than $n^8$ starting from some rank.

Comment: Sure, I know the previous question I asked already answers this one, but the math referenced there seemed disappointingly deep. This is a strictly easier question and I'm hoping there's an "elementary" proof that doesn't talk about how irrational $\pi$ is.

Comment: I don't see how.  If you replace $\sin(n)$ by $\sin(r \pi n/2)$ where $r$ is a rational number with odd numerator, the sum would diverge.  It would also diverge if you used $\sin(\alpha n)$ where $\alpha$ can be very well approximated by $r \pi/2$ for such rationals $r$.
So in order to prove it, you must somehow show that $1$ can't be so approximated.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, the success of the comparison test relies on the fact that $|sin(n)|^{n^8}$ converges (As mentioned by the OP). Though, it seems that this isn't what OP is looking for.